# Android layout advice (RecyclerView, ViewPager and CardView)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I need some advice to implement a design for my android application.

I'm using a `RecyclerView` to display a list of `CardView`. No problem with that. But, I need a top section with a `ViewPager` that display other `CardView` with horizontal swipping:

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/akg2i.png

I've read that `Viewpager` is not very built to be in a `RecyclerView`, so maybe a better way is to create a `ScrollView` with a `ViewPager` inside then a `RecyclerView` below and disable the scrolling of the `RecyclerView` ?

Also, can I use `ViewPager` view along with `CardView` ?

EDIT:

Ok problem resolved: I tried with this solution from fmt.Println.MKO's comment

> you can do this, define 2 Items types, one for your usual cards, and one for your 2.RecyclerView, with int getItemViewType(int position), you return the specific type. and in onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) you create a viewholder depending on type, either just your card or the 2. RecyclerView

In my `PostCardAdapter` used by both `RecyclerView`:

```
   @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            RecyclerItem p = items.get(position);
            if (p.isHeader){
                return TYPE_HEADER;
            }
            return TYPE_POST;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_HEADER:
                RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_header, viewGroup, false);
                rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
                PostsCardAdapter adapter2 = new PostsCardAdapter(this.headerPosts);
                rv.setAdapter(adapter2);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(viewGroup.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                return new HeaderViewHolder(rv);

            default:
                View postView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post, viewGroup, false);
                return new PostsViewHolder(postView);
        }

    }
```

Nothing specific to do in the `onBindViewHolder` for `TYPE_HEADER`

Just need to apply the scrollTo method to act like a viewPager and find a solution to display a component with circles indicating wich item is showed.

Comment: "Also, can I use ViewPager view CardView ?". yes. For the rest, could you maybe add a small design mockup for what you want to display? Especially for "But, I need a top section[...]".

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. I won't provide an answer, because I really don't know how usebility friendly the recycler view and view pager will work together - but I suggest just implement the Recycler View with a ViewHolder pattern for the Custom Items. Within these custom items (use a relative layout) add the view pager on top and the two cardviews below. Both, Recycler View and ViewPager don't need much time to implement. Test it and provide the result. Additonal: I would not use your second approach.

Comment: @fmt.Println.MKO  could you please help me on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707968/android-layout-advice-recyclerview-viewpager-and-cardview ] same. Actually I need this type of cardview with swipe in viewpager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understood you have a horizontal scrolling view, and vertical scrolling view below.

todo this, you have to add two RecyclerView's in your activity / fragment layout.xml

on your first RecyclerView you add a LinearLayoutManager ,with a horizontal orientation.

you don't need a viewpager for that.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to use ViewPager's functionnality such as: display only 1 item, auto scroll the list when the swipping begins and display current 'page' number in a separate control ?

Comment: yes, just make the width of the top card to match the screen width, and a scroll listener, which calls the scrollTo method from LayoutoutManager of the other RecyclerView

Comment: No, I just need the ViewPager to display 4 items. Like a slideshow.

Comment: Ah I see. There might be a problem if the viewPager would be within the recycler view, but if not, I don't see a problem then with using a ViewPager above the recycler view?

Comment: @JacksOnF1re, thats true, I just suggested two RecyclerViews, because then you need to think only about one ViewType

Comment: I've tested the solution with two RecyclerViews: the problem is that the first horizontal RecyclerView always stay on screen. I would like it to scroll when the user scroll down the second RecyclerView. I tried to put the two RecyclerView inside a ScrollView but it seems to make some trouble...

Comment: ah , so your 1. RecyclerView should be the first Element of  the 2. RecyclerView ? then you can do this, define 2 Items types, one for your usual cards, and one for your 2.RecyclerView, with int getItemViewType(int position), you return the specific type. and in onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) you create a viewholder depending on type, either just your card or the 2. RecyclerView

Comment: haha, I was not that incorrect then :) I would go with fmt.Println's answer, too.